# Get the password key when using the wp_new_user_notification_email filter

Tags: plugin-development, customization, user-registration

I'm trying to customize the email sent to newly registered users. I use the `wp_new_user_notification_email` filter in a plugin, and it's working fine to set the subject and message. However **I would like to send the link to reset the user's password the same way the normal WP notification email does**.

From what I see in the `wp_new_user_notification` function, the password key in hashed before being stored in the database. This key is then used in the url to reset the password. The problem is that I cannot access this variable in the function I call with the `wp_new_user_notification_email` filter, and if I generate a randow key to put in the url WP throws an error in the form (probably because the new key doesn't correspond to the stored hashed key).

I guess there is a way to achieve this, because having a filter to customize the registration message without giving the link to reset the password would be pretty pointless.

Any idea ?

Answer (score 6):

I found a function to retrieve this key : get_password_reset_key().

So now I have this code in my plugin to customize the email sent to newly registered users:

```
    add_filter('wp_new_user_notification_email', 'change_notification_message', 10, 3);

    function change_notification_message( $wp_new_user_notification_email, $user, $blogname ) {

        // Generate a new key
        $key = get_password_reset_key( $user );

        // Set the subject
        $wp_new_user_notification_email['subject'] = __('Your email subject');

        // Put the username in the message
        $message = sprintf(__('Username: %s'), $user->user_login) . "\r\n\r\n";
        // Give your user the link to reset her password 
        $message .= __('To set your password, visit the following address:') . "\r\n\r\n";
        $message .= '<' . network_site_url("wp-login.php?action=rp&key=$key&login=" . rawurlencode($user->user_login), 'login') . ">\r\n\r\n";

        $message .= wp_login_url() . "\r\n";

        // Set the email's message
        $wp_new_user_notification_email['message'] = $message;

        return $wp_new_user_notification_email;
    }
```